# How to fix, "Error: Request failed with status code 404" in axios Next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, axios, next.js

> I am using next js when trying to call an API endpoint(dispatching a
>   redux action)in getInitialProps. I am getting the 404 error, my /api/
>   is proxied in nginx server, all other routes work very well only this
>   route is causing the problem.
>
> I have tried by changing the api fetch function call to async but
>   still the same error.

```
static async getInitialProps({ store, query: { id } }) {
    await store.dispatch(fetchP(id));
    console.log('GetIntial');
    return { id };
 }
```

> My action creator

```
export const fetchp = id => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_P_DETAILS_STARTED });
  await API.get(`ps/${id}`)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_P_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data.data,
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      if (!err.response) {
        // network error
        err.message = 'Error: Network Error';
        console.log(err.message);
      } else if (err.code === 'ECONNABORTED') {
        console.log('Timeout');
      } else {
        err.message = err.message;
      }
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_P_DETAILS_FAILURE,
        payload: err.message,
      });
    });
};
```

> My nginx config

```
  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
```

> Error Response  Error: Request failed with status code 404
>       at createError (/home/ubuntu/mainWebApp/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
>       at settle (/home/ubuntu/mainWebApp/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:18:12)
>       at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/home/ubuntu/mainWebApp/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:202:11)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:198:15)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1139:12)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:17)

Comment: what does `console.log(id)` return inside `getInitialProps`

Comment: @evgeni fotia it prints the correct id value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the problem is that getInitialProps get executed in the server and axios can not run the server use https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch instead.

Comment: i tried to console.log(id) in getIntialProps but it is not logging in console, I think getInitialprops is not executed.

Comment: @AbhiKanimilli try `console.log('Heloooooooooooo')` because what you say doesn't make sense if `getIntialProps` doesn't get executed there will be no request

Comment: await store.dispatch(fetchPg(id));
    console.log('Heloooooooooooo');
    console.log(id);

Comment: if i log after dispatch it is not loging

Comment: @AbhiKanimilli that's normal. the important is that it log `id` before `await API.get(`ps/${id}`)`. so just change axios to the above package

Comment: before await API.get() it is logging the correct id to console.

Comment: @AbhiKanimilli if the above package worked for you mark the qestion as answered ✔

Comment: i am trying to use above package but it gives 
TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported

Comment: @AbhiKanimilli https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/1213#issuecomment-280978022